# Plotting Single Quiver Arrow with basemap

Tags: matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

New to Python, I know this is an easy question with a one line answer but I can't figure it out.

I'm trying to plot a single quiver arrow on top of a basemap with a single longitude and latitude coordinate point but I'm getting errors when trying to plot the quiver.

Here's what I have so far:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lat,lon=28.31393296,-96.63100599
u,v=6.16,-3.02
m=Basemap(projection='mill',llcrnrlon=-96.9,llcrnrlat=28.245,
    urcrnrlon=-96.587,urcrnrlat=28.485,resolution='i')
m.drawcoastlines()
m.fillcontinents(color='coral',lake_color='aqua')
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')
m.quiver(lon,lat,u,v,latlon=True)
plt.show()
```

And I'm getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-46-c277f7618784>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('C:/animationtest.py', wdir='C:')

File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 685, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 71, in execfile
exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

File "C:/animationtest.py", line 41, in <module>
m.quiver(lon,lat,ve,vn,latlon=True)

File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap\__init__.py", line 556, in with_transform
x1, u = self.shiftdata(x, u)

File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap\__init__.py", line 4713, in shiftdata
raise ValueError('1-d or 2-d longitudes required')

ValueError: 1-d or 2-d longitudes required
```

Can someone please explain why this doesn't work?

EDIT: Figured out the solution, had to convert lat lon to map projection with the line

```
x,y=m(lon,lat)
```

And then plot the quiver with

```
m.quiver(x,y,u,v)
```

Does exactly what I needed to do

Comment: You should write up your solution as an answer and accept it!